# Signed equivalent of a 2's complement hex value

Tags: python, c, signed

On the python terminal when I do :-

```
In [6]: 0xffffff85
Out[6]: 4294967173

In [9]: "%d" %(0xffffff85)
Out[9]: '4294967173'
```

I'd like to be able to give in `0xffffff85` and get the signed equivalent decimal number in python(in this case `-123`). How could I do that?

In C, I could do it as :-

```
int main() { int x = 0xffffff85; printf("%d\n", x); }
```

Comment: If it's not smaller than 2 to the power of (bitlength-1), subtract 2 to the power of bitlength. Easy. (Bitlength in this case is 32)

Comment: `int x = 0xffffff85; printf("%d\n", x);` is not portable C code to print "-123".  This depends on the bit width of `unsigned`, `int` and the underlying `int` implementation (2's complement or not.)  The C code is UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) library.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_int32(0xffffff85).value
-123
```

You can also do the same using [`bitstring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3) library.

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> BitArray(uint = 0xffffff85, length = 32).int
-123L
```

Without external / internal libraries you could do :

```
int_size = 32
a = 0xffffff85
a = (a ^ int('1'*a.bit_length())) + 1 if a.bit_length() == int_size else a
```

This takes the 2's complement of the number `a`, if the `bit_length()` of the number `a` is equal to your `int_size` value. `int_size` value is what you take as the maximum bit length of your signed binary number [ here `a` ].

Assuming that the number is signed, an `int_size` bit negative number will have its first bit ( sign bit ) set to 1. Hence the `bit_length` will be equal to the `int_size`.

Comment: Here's another for your collection: `import struct; struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('I', 0xffffff85))[0]`