# Converting Hex data to signed integer in python

Tags: python, signed

I'm fetching a value(2 bytes) from a register using AARDVARK python module. The value are returned in Hex format. So I convert the value to decimal.Since the register value can be negative, I need to convert to signed integer if required. 
I came across the following piece of code that does this and I'm unable to fathom the logic behind it.

```
myValue = int(myValue,16)
if( myValue > 32768):
      myValue = ((myValue+0x8000)&0xFFFF) - 0x8000
```

For example if myValue read from register is 32769 , the corresponding signed representation after using the above piece of code is -32767

Comment: Can you give us some examples of negative and positive values? Is this using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent both positive and negative numbers?

Comment: See [Two's complement of Hex number in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26641664) and [Signed equivalent of a 2's complement hex value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25096755) for examples.